# php artisan serve (terminated) in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, vue.js, laravel-5.3, ubuntu-16.04, laravel-artisan

I am having issue with running `php artisan serve`. When I run the port it throws an error after some time "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 160+2 seconds exceeded (terminated) in Unknown on line 0"

see the screen shot. [Screen Shot Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYjaA.png)

I am running the `yarn run watch:core` to watch the file.